# Unable to get Contact ID to display in Custom Field

Tags: contacts

Been stuck on this for the past few days I want to set a default value for a custom field in a contribution. The Custom fields are associated by Financial Types,  I intend to show the current contact id of the person the contribution is being submitted for in a custom field. I tried doing this originally within the CustomDatabyType.php file.

```
class CRM_Custom_Form_CustomDataByType extends CRM_Core_Form {

  public function setDefaultValues() {
    $contact_id = CRM_Core_Form::getContactID();
    $defaults = [];
    $defaults['custom_224_-1'] = $contact_id;
    CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::setDefaults($this->_groupTree, $defaults, FALSE, FALSE, $this->get('action'));
    return $defaults;
  }
}
```

To Clarify the reason i want the contact ID for the user i am submitting the form for is because i want to display that contacts 'Employer' in a custom field. I have tried the following:

```
CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cid', 'Positive');
$form->getContactID();
$form->_contactID;
```

The issue i am having is that is the above lines of code work if i associate it to a field within the contribution form but if i associate it to a custom field it will show the contactID of the user submitting the form not the user of whom the form is being submitting for.

I have also tried to do this via a custom buildForm hook:

```
function dfi_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {

    if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution' || $form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
        $thisContactID = $form->_contactID;
        $defaults['custom_224_-1'] = $thisContactID;
       $form->setDefaults($defaults);
    }
}
```

I hope i have been clear and i would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

---

An Idea i have had is to set the ContactID within a field in the 'Contribution section' use getVar to get the value of the field and then assign that value to the custom field.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try instead with hook_civicrm_buildForm and use `$form->setDefaults()`

Comment: @Demerit - Its not working unfortunately.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15012#issuecomment-520766849 - Found this however it only works for Activity Custom Fields not Contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using the following code:

```
        $getSessionArray = CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->get('CRM_Utils_Recent');
        $thisContactID = $getSessionArray[0]['id'];
```

Comment: Great. Just a note for others that if you remove Contacts from the list at Administer - System Settings - Misc where it says "Recent Items Providers" then this might fail, but I'd guess that very few sites do that.